# Perform calculations in a UIView subclass breaks the MVC's design pattern?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, uiview, multi-touch

I have a UIView subclass in which I override the multi-touch handling methods. My question is, if I perform calculations with the given touches on that view, it breaks the Model View Controller design pattern?. After calculations, I have to hide the view, print the results and update my Core Data model. I am confused about this.

**EDIT:**

Some code.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // getting all the touches in the given gesture sequence
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

    // checking taps count
    if ([allTouches count] == 3)
    {
        // here I print the results and do the calculations
        [self validateGestureSequenceWithTouches:allTouches];
    }

    // cleaning the view
    NSArray *subviews = [self subviews];
    for (UIView *view in subviews) {
       if (![view isKindOfClass:[UINavigationBar class]])
           [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to stay within the MVC guidelines, your business-level calculations need to happen in your model layer. However, not all calculations qualify as "business calculations": very often you must perform calculations to decide on UI matters, such as

- Visibility of individual UI elements
- Size of individual ui elements,
- Locations and direction of touches,

and so on. If your calculations are of the business kind, then you should move it into the model. Otherwise, keeping it in the view or the controller is preferred.

Comment: You mean "keeping it in the view or controller", I assume.

Comment: It is a good practice to send a callback method with the results from the view so that the controller can manage the results?. I mean, I would have it from a UIViewController, but it is good to do it from a UIView subclass?.

Comment: @ThXou This depends on a kind of logic that you are trying to implement: if the calculation can be shared among views, or when it is not specific to a view, placing it into the controller is a good idea. On the other hand, when the computation is heavily view-specific, keeping it with the view is better.

Comment: The view is performing some math with the location of the touches. If the result of that calculation is iqual to a token, then I have to hide the view and update my Core Data db. I think I understand: I do the calculation and hide the view, after, I send a message to the model passing it the result?, like `[model saveWithResult:result]`?

Comment: @ThXou Anything related to location on screen belongs with the view, not the view controller. When the view decides that it needs to close, as the result of recognizing a particular sequence of touches, it calls back the model or the controller to inform them of its decision. So the `[model saveWithResult:result]` call looks right.